# como puedo hacer bien esta consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos

Hola soy estudiante de Ing de sistemas y en mi clase de BD nos pusieron unos ejercicios, la mayoria no se me hacen muy complicados pero hay un punto que dice "Haga una seleccion que devuelva lo adeudado por el cliente"
Esto fue lo que yo hice [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

mi problema es que donde dice total pagado deberia retornar 4000 ya que al hacer la consulta por si sola de la tabla pagos es lo que devuelve de ese cliente[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
trate de pedirle ayuda a mi profesor pero no quiso ayudar y la verdad ya no se me ocurre y la verdad me interesa por que quiero meterme en la rama de BD si alguien puede ayudarme a corregir el error se lo agradezco

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Por favor, incluye tus consultas a la base de datos como texto formateado. Y añade la estructura de tus tablas. ¿Porque en tu consulta TOTAL_PEDIDO y TOTAL_ADEUDADO son iguales? Por otro lado no puedes hacer INNER  JOIN entre los pedidos y los pagos por cliente. Así añades un pago determinado a todos los pedidos que haya hecho. Es decir si el cliente pagó 4000 e hizo tres pedidos, te está saliendo que pagó 12000.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y pon tanto las consultas como los datos de ejemplo _como texto, con formato_. ¡No se puede hacer _copypaste_ de imágenes! Además, [no todos pueden visualizarlas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/).

Comment: Porque en la 1ra consulta haces `sum(cantidad*preciounidad)` y en la 2da solo haces `sum(cantidad)`

Comment: Hola. son dos tablas diferentes una es de una tabla detallepedido y en la segunda consulta es de la tabla pagos que en la primera consulta significaria total pagado y como ves dan resultados distintos siendo el de la segunda consulta el correcto